# Listing attributes of nodes in a table

Tags: list, neo4j, group-by, cypher

I'm busy working on a fictional data set of short term car insurance claims. The data is structured like this:

```
Name        Claim_ID     Claim_Amount    Date_Processed   etc...
Sam Smith   JT367214     3764.89         06/13/2011       etc...
```

The question I have is that some people have submitted more than one claim within the year. I want to view who submitted more than one claim using their name as a unique ID. The data must first be sorted by the amount of claims per client and then be sorted by Date_Processed. Thus my resulting table must look like this:

```
Name         Claim_ID     Claim_Amount    Date_Processed
Sam Smith    JT367214     3764.89         06/13/2011   
             LK592814     234.67          07/19/2011 
             MT329164     1000.00         08/02/2011
Matt Jones   LK678321     5674.00         02/03/2011
```

Currently the code I am using looks like this:

```
MATCH(a:Client) - [f:Submitted_Claim] - (b:Claim)
WITH a.Name_Surname as Client, b.Claim_ID as Claim_ID, b.day as Claim_Day, b.month as Claim_Month, count(f) as Number_of_claims
RETURN Client, Claim_ID, Claim_Day, Claim_Month
ORDER BY Number_of_claims DESC
```

This works but it only gives individual claims and not all claims per client grouped together.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return the clients with the most claims first, and each client will have a date-sorted collection of claims data:

```
MATCH(a:Client)-[f:Submitted_Claim]-(b:Claim)
WITH a.Name_Surname AS Client, b.Claim_ID AS cId, b.day AS cd, b.month AS cm
ORDER BY cm, cd
RETURN
  Client,
  COLLECT({Claim_ID: cId, Claim_Day: cd, Claim_Month: cm}) AS data
ORDER BY SIZE(data) DESC
```